# What would little people eat and how would they gather food?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, creature-design

In my world a group of little people  (about 3 inches tall) live in a meadow. What sources of food would be available to them in this environment(  their digestive biology is the same as ours).

Something that they could grow or gather that wouldn't get them killed  (i.e required within to climb a tree or attach the army of angry ants.

Locations upstate New York

Comment: There are about a million answers to this question Bryan, can you narrow things down at all?

Comment: Start by giving us a location. Where are these micro-men living? What is available really depends in location. Southern Illinois? Ukraine and southern Russia? Western Europe? Of course, this is assuming your 'world' takes place on Earth, because otherwise we have no way to answer than to suggest extremely general ideas such as "well, insects."

Comment: Upstate New York means they'll have to also deal with their meadow being buried in several feet of snow for almost half the year.

Comment: @fiend They will have to domesticate voles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insects, seeds, mice would be 'large' game.  Berries would be a huge windfall...

Strawberry plants would be very useful.  Acorns are digestible by humans but you need to 'acclimate' to the taste.  Pine nuts would likely be a very good source of protein and fat.  There are lots of cherry trees out there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Berries/ nuts and small insects perhaps . Mice , probably not , cause mice would be around the same size as them .This would make mice hard to kill and eat . Maybe fruits (when they fall from trees ), where say a mango could be cut up and eaten by multiple people .  Those would provide vitamins / minerals . Nuts would provide good fat for them .

Comment: I would argue that protein would come primarily from large hunted insects. They breed quickly and are packed with protein.

Comment: But insects would be hard for the mini-humans to bring down - might result in loss of life .

Comment: Depends on the insect. Hunt caterpillars and dig in fallen logs for grubs. Just avoid the predatory ones (ants, wasps, spiders, mantises) to the best of their ability and travel in groups.